How to fix "unable to start program js-debug the debugger is not properly installed"
I am unable to find a solution to this issue anywhere.
Whenever I run my project (React + ASP.NET Core), it opens a command line window that runs the front-end using vite. But along with it comes this popup that gives the error "unable to start program js-debug the debugger is not properly installed".
I have tried disabling and enabling "Enable JS debugging in Chrome, Edge, etc." in the debugger tab.

The issue is commonly caused by misconfiguration in launchersettings or a missing debugger installation.You may try deleting the LauncherSettings.json under folder Properties and see if the problem still exist.

Hi @Hideki Namikawa, try to navigate to the react prject and find the start command, start it in terminal manually in that folder. Check if it is works or not ? Then set asp.net core webapi as the startup project to see if it can run alone.
